# Set Text 'Not Attempted' in Date field

Tags: date, fields, inputtext, default-value

Is it possible to input a default 'text' to a Date Field. which will change to a date as soon as the person attempts something

Comment: Where you want to show this placeholder? in VF?

Comment: fields can take default values right? so in a date field area i want a text, until it is changed

Comment: Date field can't take text as default value. But you can display place holder in visualforce page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't mix return types of a field. But, you could create a formula field, which returns either a text date, or a text string.

```
IF((ISBLANK(SomeDate__c)), 'No Attempt', TEXT(SomeDate__c))
```